# Getting source and destination must be different error while building project

Tags: android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I am getting this error while building project. Trying to add a new library in android-studio. Is there anybody who has an idea basically I am trying to create a new library here.

Options tried:

1. Manually deleted build
2. Invaildate cache/restart
3. Gradle clean build cache
4. Build->Clean Project

   But build is failing.

   Source C:\Users\abc\AndroidStudioProjects\Events\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so and destination C:\Users\abc\AndroidStudioProjects\Events\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so must be different

CMakeLists.txt I am using for the same:

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp
        )

add_library (
        testLib
        SHARED
        TestClassesManager.cpp
)
# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib}

        )

target_link_libraries(
        testLib

        native-lib
)
```

The error goes away if I am replacing

```
target_link_libraries(
        testLib

        native-lib
)
```

by

```
target_link_libraries(
        testLib
    ${log-lib}

)
```

But I want to link both libraries. But it is giving above error. Please help.

Comment: When is this error produced? When you run CMake? When you compile the project (after running CMake)? Please provide the steps you take to produce this error.

Comment: @squareskittles,  Just create a project. Add TestClassesManager.cpp class in your cpp folder. All above cmakeLists.txt in your code. Then you should be able to reproduce it. Please suggest how can I add these two libraries separately.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't answer my question. Does the error occur during the CMake *configuration* stage, or during the stage at which your code is being *compiled*? It may be helpful to provide the full log that is shown, with any message surrounding the error you've shown. Also, is this the *only* CMake file in your project?

Comment: @squareskittles, this error occurs when the code is being compiled. This is the only logs I am getting. Yes, this is only cmakefile in my project. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 7):

This is a *weird* bug, but thank you for the concise repro project. Actually had someone mention this to me the other day but I hadn't had any luck reproducing the failure.

I'm still investigating [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/158317988), but for now it seems that a workaround is to run clean, then refresh linked c++ projects, then build. If you need to use the "refresh linked c++ projects" button, again, run clean *first*.

A fix has been cherry-picked and will be in 4.0.1.

Comment: For me the clean-refresh-build sequence did not work. Going back to gradle plugin 3.6.2 seems to be the only workaround for me until a fix is released.

Comment: Could be there are cases where that won't help (and neither will anything else). Root cause was that the model generation task was broken if it ran from a non-clean build. If you're doing something else that would cause that to regenerate (probably not hard to do, but I don't  know all the circumstances that cause it), there probably isn't a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I am running into the same issue. The problem seems to be SHARED attribute. My guess is that all shared libraries are assumed to be "final" libraries that are JNI libraries.

A workaround for developing is to mark the library that are dependencies STATIC instead.

Also doing a fresh build (remove the .cxx and all build directories) seems not have the issue but every rebuild after that.

Comment: can you tell me exactly how should I build 2 libraries which are dependent upon native-lib in cmakeLists.txt.

Comment: Change the type of native-lib from SHARED to STATIC in your example. This is currently a workaround until the real underlying issue in the Android build system is fixed.

Comment: Yes, great ! I have changed to STATIC in CMakeLists.txt (in the add_library command) then "Build/Make Project" then changed again to SHARED then "Build/Make Project" and all is fine for me ! Simple but great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the steps you mentioned worked for me either. you can look at According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62223434/1388084), it is a bug and the final solution for me was to go back to my previous gradle version.

Answer (score -1):

What I understand and feel is your plugins is not the right version for your current sdk version or in-compactible.

Try to lower the plugin version or apply newer version might also help. Make sure to use the lastest Android Studion and try checking again. If the further error log is available, kindly paste here.

Comment: @Marurata, No the error goes away if I am replacing target_link_libraries(
        testLib

        native-lib
) by target_link_libraries(
        testLib

        
)

Comment: See my edit now. Basically I want to add two seperate libraries

Comment: I have the same problem and I can confirm that this is the full error log. There is only a log line. linking xxx.so before that.

Answer (score -1):

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

add_library(native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp)

add_library(native STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(native
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/libenative-lib.so)


target_link_libraries(
        testLib
        native
)
```

yeah， this is work .