# Android studio NDK Gradle build "Source ... and destination ... must be different"

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Android Studio with NDK, Gradle and CMake to build several shared libraries and link them together.

I keep getting the same error again and again in the build log:

```
:app:processDebugManifest [Passed]
:app:externalNativeBuildDebug [Passed]

Source C:\XXX\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libBGS-d.so and destination C:\XXX\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libBGS-d.so must be different
```

It's like gradle is trying to copy my library at the same position.
The thing is, I have no idea where this instruction comes from and how I can debug it. There's really not much indication in the build log.

What's confusing is that is doesn't occur 100% of the time. Seems like there is a race condition somewhere. Also sometimes it's another library that triggers the build to fail. Also, cleaning the project doesn't help.

So here's my question: is there any place where I can get granular control over the Gradle build sequence ?

Answer (score 2):

According to Dan Albert at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62223434/8068814 this appears to be a bug and he suggests cleaning the project, then triggering "refresh linked c++ projects" and then building the project. Since it is sometimes working for you, this might be a reliable solution in your case.

For me this did not help, but reverting the Gradle plugin to 3.6.2 was the only way for me to build my project.

Comment: Oh. Not sure how I missed that obvious duplicate.Thanks.